# Installing Jenkins

Tags: java, jenkins

I could not install the jenkins, below is the step by step that realized:

1) Downloaded the jenkins.war file that is in the folder C:\Users\Rafael\Downloads

2) Entered at the command prompt, and accessed the folder in which it is and then ran the command java-jar jenkins.war

3) It was extracted successfully. All files are created.

4) When I access the address localhost: 8080 or meu_ip: 8080 does not work.

What am I doing wrong?

Note: the same process above, I did on wamp www folder also, but also did not work.

Comment: is this on windows or linux?

Answer (score 1):

try adding a "/jenkins" to the end of your host:port url. so http:// localhost : 8080 / jenkins [no spaces]

Comment: I got it. Thank you!

Do you know how to run junit test in the jenkins?

Comment: @Jeff welcome to stackoveflow. If someone helped you it's polite to accept their first answer before asking a second one.